# Two Where conditions on same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are several status an the status table. I want query like that.

```
select * from command where status <> 's' and status<> 'sc'
```

But query retrieve data with 'Status' S.
What was the issue on that?

Comment: What is the data type and collation of the column `status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checks `Col <> 's'` depends on the collation of the columns. If the collation is case insensitive, then `'S' = 's'` and your checks will not return `S`. If your collation is case sensitive which I believe is the case, will return `S`.

For example note the following two collations `Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS` and `Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS`. Note the difference in case `CI` and `CS`.

```
SELECT 'S' WHERE 'S' <> 's' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS
```

Does not return anything

```
SELECT 'S' WHERE 'S' <> 's' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS
```

Returns `S`

Coming back to your query. If this case insensitive check is a one time thing you can either as suggested by other answers do a `UPPER(Col)` / `LOWER(Col)` or use `COL COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS`.

If all comparisons should be case insensitive, I would suggest [changing the collation of the column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx) itself.

Answer (score 6):

Is the status in the DB `S` or `s`?

Try

```
select * from command where lower(status) NOT IN ('s', 'sc')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try it.. No need to check lower or caps. It searches all letter (not case sensitive).

```
select * from command where status NOT IN ('s', 'sc')
```

If you want to add condition with case sensitive, then you have to use like this..

```
select * from command where status COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS NOT IN ('s', 'sc')
```